# Remove all bytes after null byte (\x00)

Tags: python

I have a python client that receives a string from a C server. I always receive a 6 byte string, in C everything after the '\0' byte is junk, so on my client I need to remove all the bytes after that null byte. How exactly can I do that on a byte object? I tried converting it to string and then removing it but it didn't seem to work

I have something like this `b'str\x00...'` where `...` represents the junk bytes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bytes` have a [`.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.split) method like `str`:

```
>>> b = b'str\x00...'
>>> b.split(b'\x00')[0]
b'str'
```

Comment: Worth noting that this is still valid even if `b` doesn't contain a null byte.